# Rsync error in Vagrant 2.2.3 (IPC code) when updating

Tags: ssh, vagrant, rsync

I've an issue when updating a [Vagrant](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10667) box (Vagrant 2.2.3 and Windows 10).

The cause of error is rsync, it can't synchronize (so, my shared folders are not working, I think) :

```
Command: "rsync" "--verbose" "--archive" "--delete" "-z" "--copy-links" "--chmod=ugo=rwX" "--no-perms" "--no-owner" "--no-group" "--rsync-path" "sudo rsync" "-e" "ssh -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL    -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/my_user/boxes-puphpet/debian/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'" "--exclude" ".vagrant/" "/cygdrive/c/Users/my_user/boxes-puphpet/debian/" "vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant"

Error: rsync: pipe: Connection timed out (116)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(59) [sender=3.1.3]

 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::RSyncError", "There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.\nPlease inspect the error message below for more info.\n\nHost path: /cygdrive/c/Users/my_user/boxes-puphpet/debian/\nGuest path: /vagrant\nCommand: \"rsync\" \"--verbose\" \"--archive\" \"--delete\" \"-z\" \"--copy-links\" \"--chmod=ugo=rwX\" \"--no-perms\" \"--no-owner\" \"--no-group\" \"--rsync-path\" \"sudo rsync\" \"-e\" \"ssh -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL    -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/my_user/boxes-puphpet/debian/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'\" \"--exclude\" \".vagrant/\" \"/cygdrive/c/Users/my_user/boxes-puphpet/debian/\" \"vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant\"\nError: rsync: pipe: Connection timed out (116)\nrsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(59) [sender=3.1.3]\n"]
```

Here my Vagranfile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.box_version = "8.10.0"

   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.222"

   config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/f.pestre/www/debian.vm/www/", "/var/www"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4048"
  end

   #config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"      
end
```

I can login with vagrant ssh, but the sync folder doesn't work, at all.

Thanks.
F.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your vagrant file

```
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
```